# Creating .dat file (fstream) c++

Tags: c++, fstream, createfile

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main() {

fstream inOutGrades( "grades.dat", ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary );

if ( !inOutGrades ) {
    cerr << "The file could not be opened." << endl;
    exit(1);
}

return 0;
}

//Output is 
The file could not be opened.
```

I've tried this program wioth QT and Code::blocks at windows 7 and lubuntu.They all can't create the grades.dat file.

Comment: Check if you have the write permission of the working directory.

Comment: I can create .txt files with the same way.I think it's about writing permissions.And i also don't know how can i check this permissions?

Comment: In situations like this you should log the I/O error: `cerr << "The file could not be opened: " << strerror(errno) << endl;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `ios::in` and the file should be created. You cannot specify `ios::in` if a file does not exist. However, if you add `ios::trunc` you are able to specify both `ios::in` and `ios::out` since you are starting with an empty file.

Answer (score 0):

```
fstream FHandle;
FHandle.open("grades.dat", ios::out);
if(FHandle.is_open())
    cout << "Opened !";
else
    cout << "Not Opened !";
```

This should work.

Comment: That is the same as the one in the question. fstream has `!` operator and he can give file name and flags to the constructor, as well.